# How to return multiple values using mulitple criteria in Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula, valuestack

I am trying to return multiple values using multiple criteria...below is the code I have tried (but using the special brackets) but it keeps coming back as though I am trying to create a sum and have an error...

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(Sheet2!$C$4:$C$25,SMALL((IF(Sheet2!$D$4:$D$41=Sheet3!G2)*(Sheet2!$E$4:$E$67=Sheet3!$L$3),ROW(Sheet2!C4:C24)),ROW(1:1))),"")
```

Below is a code that returns one result, but there are multiple names for the two matching criteria.

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(Sheet2!$C$4:$E$43,MATCH(1,(Sheet2!$D$4:$D$26=Sheet3!$G$2)*(Sheet2!$E$4:$E$26=Sheet3!$L$3),0),1)," ")
```

essentially, I have a stakeholder analysis square - broken down into:

- Keep Satisfied (Sheet 3: cell `C2`)
- Manage closely (Sheet 3: cell `G2`)
- Keep Informed (Sheet 3: cell `C13`)
- Monitor (Sheet 3: cell `GG13`)

I am using a data validation in sheet 3: cell `L11` (linked to Sheet 2), to create the second criteria (project).

What I would like to happen is for it to return the names into each of the stakeholder analysis headings. The problem is, if for example, I have 3 names in 'manage closely' for one project  - I cannot get it to return all three names...only the one.

This has been driving me insane

Comment: cell G3 - not cell GG3

Answer (score 0):

There are several errors in the first formula you give, i.e.:

`=IFERROR(INDEX(Sheet2!$C$4:$C$25,SMALL((IF(Sheet2!$D$4:$D$41=Sheet3!G2)*(Sheet2!$E$4:$E$67=Sheet3!$L$3),ROW(Sheet2!C4:C24)),ROW(1:1))),"")`

For one, the ranges passed should be **of an identical size**; in your case, all four are different, viz:

`Sheet2!$C$4:$C$25`: 22 rows

`Sheet2!$D$4:$D$41`: 38 rows

`Sheet2!$E$4:$E$67`: 64 rows

`Sheet2!C4:C24`: 21 rows

I can only guess at what should be the correct range, so let's assume the largest for the sake of argument.

Secondly, I assume that the reference:

`Sheet3!G2`

should actually be **absolute**, i.e.

`Sheet3!$G$2`

so as to be invariable as this formula is copied down?

I will also make a few other corrections, to the *value_if_true* clause being used for the `IF` statement (the one you are currently using is not correct), and also to `SMALL`'s k parameter (`ROWS` is more robust than `ROW` here: https://excelxor.com/2014/08/25/row-vs-rows-for-consecutive-integer-generation/).

All in all:

`=IFERROR(INDEX(Sheet2!$C:$C,SMALL(IF(Sheet2!$D$4:$D$67=Sheet3!$G$2,IF(Sheet2!$E$4:$E$67=Sheet3!$L$3,ROW(Sheet2!$C$4:$C$67))),ROWS($1:1))),"")`

and copied down.

You might also want to take note that, if the ranges being questioned are in fact quite large, the use of `IFERROR` can here be very inefficient:

https://superuser.com/questions/812727/look-up-a-value-in-a-list-and-return-all-multiple-corresponding-values/812848

Regards

Comment: Many thanks for your help. -  I have managed to fix it, before I got to this today...new formula looks like:=IFERROR(INDEX(Sheet2!C:C,SMALL(IF((Sheet2!D:D='SH Tool'!$G$2)*(Sheet2!E:E='SH Tool'!$L$3),ROW(Sheet2!E:E)),ROW(D3)))," ") - I will add (to my detriment i'm sure) I have no idea why there is the final ROW(D3). I just followed a guide somewhere else but there was no real explanation as to why that is there. initially it was D1 but changed when I dragged it down due to it not being absolute. D1 is an empty cell...all of D is empty...

Comment: It's not at all a good idea to reference entire columns in an array formula. Looks like you haven't heeded my advice re IFERROR either.